# how to bind to parent's grid property

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a grid inside a grid and I want to check a property of the parent grid to set up the background of the child grid. I tried using RelativeSource but I keep getting a *Cannot find source for binding* error.

```
<telerik:RadGridView name="parent"
  <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
     <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <telerik:RadGridView Name="child" ...  
                 <telerik:RadGridView.RowStyle>
                     <Style TargetType="telerik:GridViewRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource GridViewRowStyle}">
                         <Style.Triggers>
                          **<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding propertyofparent}" Value="1">**
                                                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                          </DataTrigger>
                          </Style.Triggers>
                     </Style>
```

Comment: So what binding path did you try? And what exact property of the RadGridView are you trying to bind to?

Comment: @mm8 I am trying to get the value of a parents column (DataMemberBinding). For example I want to check if column Country is USA. Tried your solution but I get a 'Country' property not found on object

Comment: "A parents column"? Do you mean a column in "parent"?

Comment: @mm8 yes sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bind to a property of an item (row) of "parent", this should work:

```
{Binding Path=DataContext.TheProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=telerik:RadGridView}}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `{RelativeSource}` should work if you set the `AncestorLevel` property of the `Binding` to `2`:

```
{Binding Path=Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=telerik:RadGridView,AncestorLevel=2}}
```